# Firebase deploy error : TS2694: Namespace 'admin' has no exported member 'appCheck'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, tslint

Im trying the firebase cloud function basic setup. the index.ts incldes just a hello world. but Im getting the below error when deploying the firebase cloud function.

```
node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.d.ts:109:25 - error TS2694: Namespace 'admin' has no exported member 'appCheck'.
109         token: firebase.appCheck.DecodedAppCheckToken;
Found 1 error.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
```

the Package.json file :

```
{
 "name": "functions",
 "scripts": {
   "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
   "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
   "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
   "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
   "start": "npm run shell",
   "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
   "logs": "firebase functions:log"
 },
 "engines": {
   "node": "8"
 },
 "main": "lib/index.js",
 "dependencies": {
   "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
   "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "tslint": "^5.12.0",
   "typescript": "^3.3.1",
   "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
 },
 "private": true
}
```

tsconfig.json file

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "module": "commonjs",
   "noImplicitReturns": true,
   "noUnusedLocals": true,
   "outDir": "lib",
   "sourceMap": true,
   "strict": true,
   "target": "es2017"
 },
 "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ],
 "compileOnSave": true,
 "include": [
   "src"
 ]
}
```

And I have already run the `npm install firebase-admin@latest firebase-functions@latest` to have the latest firebase dependencies.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Just hit this today too
`⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions.
Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.`

Should not have been run :-(

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Update: this has been fixed in `firebase-functions@3.14.1`, so upgrading to that version should remove the error message.

If you're still having the same problem with that version, please leave a comment below.

---

Previous answer

<strike>I asked around and from what I hear this lastest `firebase-functions` SDK requires Admin SDK 9.8.0 and Node v10 to work.</strike>

Our team is actively working on a fix, so I expect it to get better/clearer in the coming week(s).

Answer (score 0):

Until there is a better answer

```
npm i -S firebase-functions@3.13.2
```

To rollback to the last functional version